# MySQL query for date range transactions statement

Tags: mysql

I have a `transactions` table.

```
    id  account_id  trx_date    trx_type  amount  remarks  
------  ----------  ----------  --------  ------  ---------
     1           1  2017-12-10  DEPOSIT      500  test
     2           1  2017-12-11  DEPOSIT      500  test     
     3           1  2017-12-12  DEPOSIT     6000  test     
     4           1  2017-12-13  WITHDRAW     300  test     
     5           1  2017-12-13  DEPOSIT      200  test
```

I want to result in this format but I can't figure out how will be the query for fetching data like as below. Here all fields are same as `transactions` table. `op_bal`, `cl_bal` are dynamic field.

```
date            trx_type        op_bal      amount      cl_bal
2017-12-12      DEPOSIT         1000        6000            7000
2017-12-13      WITHDRAW        7000        300             6700
2017-12-13      DEPOSIT         6700        200             6900
```

Comment: What is the logic/criteria behind that result set ?

Comment: params: account_id, frm_dt, to_dt

Comment: he is asking about logic you want in the resultset. look like 60000 should be 6000.

Comment: @jit you are right. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Akashkhan you should paste your query (effort) you have done. if it is wrong also no matter. also explain for example. trx_amout relate to amount field in table. op_bal cl_bal both are dynamic likewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello for the given output I have created [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e636ec/91) please check for the answer

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id bigint(12) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    account_id bigint(12),
    trx_date date,
    trx_type enum('DEPOSIT','WITHDRAW'),
    amount float(10,2),
    remarks varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO transactions (account_id, trx_date, trx_type, amount, remarks)
VALUES ('1','2017-12-10','DEPOSIT',500,'test'),
       ('1','2017-12-11','DEPOSIT',500,'test'),
       ('1','2017-12-12','DEPOSIT',6000,'test'),
       ('1','2017-12-13','WITHDRAW',300,'test'),
       ('1','2017-12-13','DEPOSIT',200,'test');
```

and query to achieve result is

```
SELECT 
trx_date, 
trx_type, 

(SELECT SUM(CASE tr.trx_type WHEN 'DEPOSIT' THEN CONCAT('+',tr.amount) ELSE CONCAT('-', tr.amount) END) as amount FROM transactions as tr WHERE tr.id < (SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM transactions as t WHERE t.id <= transactions.id LIMIT 1) ) as op_bal,
amount AS trx_amount,
(SELECT SUM(CASE tr.trx_type WHEN 'DEPOSIT' THEN CONCAT('+',tr.amount) ELSE CONCAT('-', tr.amount) END) as amount FROM transactions as tr WHERE tr.id <= (SELECT MAX(t.id) FROM transactions as t WHERE t.id <= transactions.id LIMIT 1) ) as cl_bal
FROM transactions 
WHERE DATE(trx_date) BETWEEN '2017-12-12' AND '2017-12-13'
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: It works only for `id` based records. The result comes wrong and unexpected when trx_date changed. Please check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c3dd3/1)

Comment: you have updated date to back so you need to pass the date 2017-12-10 to 2017-12-13